# R Hmisc describe function distorted value summary

Tags: r, hmisc

I have been trying to reconcile an issue while using the describe() function within Hmisc (version 4.0-3). The unique values in the value summary appear to have been altered or misinterpreted as they don't match the results from the table() function in base R.

```
library(Hmisc)

test <- data.frame(
        'j6033' = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 2053, 2098, 0, 2053, 2098, 2, 5, 0, 0, 0, 
                    5, 13, 13, 0, 2053, 2098)
        )

describe(test$j6033)
table(test$j6033)
```

The results as I see them are:

```
> describe(test$j6033)
test$j6033 
       n  missing distinct     Info     Mean      Gmd 
      20        0        6    0.902    624.5    920.6 

Value         0    5   15 2055 2100
Frequency    10    2    2    3    3
Proportion 0.50 0.10 0.10 0.15 0.15
> table(test$j6033)

   0    2    5   13 2053 2098 
   9    1    2    2    3    3
```

Values of 2053 are interpreted as 2055, the single value of 2 has been interpreted as 0, 2098 is interpreted as 2100, and 13 is interpreted as 15. Does anyone know why there is a discrepancy here and how it can be corrected?

Note: Supporting package versions loaded by Hmisc library call are as follows: lattice (0.20-35), survival (2.41-3), Formula (1.2-2), and ggplot2 (2.2.1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function was rounding the values in some cases when there were <= 20 distinct values.  I have fixed the code to not do this binning if there are <= 20 values.  This will be in the next release.  Linux users can get the new version earlier if needed.